# "Magic" numbers are those divided by all partial digit sums: prove that there is no infinite set of "magic" powers among the natural powers of $\ell$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, statistics, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> For a natural number $n$, let $P_n$ the set of sums of each subset of digits in decimal notation of $n$. A number is magic if for each $s \in P_n$, we have $s \ | \ n$. Let's consider a number $\ell$, not divisible by $10$. Then, only a finite number of natural powers of $\ell$ are magic.

**My approach**: Proof by contradiction principle - *logic formalism principle*:
$$(\neg q \to \neg p) \leftrightarrow (p \to q)$$

In an infinite set $I$ of natural powers, we have, by *combinatorics principles* (I think Wan der Waerden?), there is an arbitrary long arithmetic progression in the exponents. So, therefore, considering an "almost infinite" progression (enough long), I'm thinking to find here a contradiction, as arithmetic progressions at the exponents do mean geometric progressions, therefore constant ratios.

I've read also some papers (*statistical approach*), that are trying to find the lower bound for number of specific digits (i. e. number of $1$s) in powers. And, therefore, try to find divisors that are mandatory in $P_{a^k}$, where $k$ is large enoungh, and here we got a contradiction, as the only divisors of $a_k$ are the powers of divisors of $a$.

However, statistical approach is not a rigurous mathematical proof, at least for my purpose, so, those assumptions could be no more than conjectures about the problem.

Please give me a hint! Any help would be appreciated.

Update: As @Vepir mentioned, "magic" numbers are super Nieven numbers.

Comment: These are called "[Super Niven numbers](https://oeis.org/A328273)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ If $l$ is not a power of $10$ then we have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\text{Digitsum}(l^n) = \infty$$

here $\text{Digitsum}(.)$ of a number is the sum of its respective digits. More details for this theorem can be found in; https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38971/sums-of-digits-of-powers-of-integers.

Now for a contradiction suppose that there are an infinite sequence of positive integers $n_{1}< n_{2},...$ so that $l^{n_{j}}$ is magic. Without loss of generality, due to the above theorem we may assume that $\text{Digitsum}(l^{n_{j}}) \geq j.$ Set

$$A_{j} = \text{ Set of sums  of each subset of digits in decimal notation of } l^{n_{j}}$$

$\textbf{Claim 1}:$ $A_{j}$ consists of atleast $\frac{j}{9}$ numbers in the interval $[1, j].$

$\textbf{Claim 2}:$ If some prime $p$ divides an element in $A_{j}$ then it divides $l$.

We see this result when one sees that each element of $A_{j}$ divides $l^{n_{j}}$.

$\textbf{Claim 3}:$ For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{j}$ has atleast $\frac{m}{9}$ integers in interval $[1, m]$

$\textbf{Claim 4}:$ For every $v \in \mathbb{N}, \exists p$ prime so that $p > v$ and $p$ divides some element of $\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{j}$.

Suppose for a contradiction that this claim is false. We can choose primes $p_1,p_{2},...,p_{k}$ so that every element of $\bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{j}$ is of the form $p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}$. Hence

$$\sum_{x \in \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{j}} \frac{1}{x} \leq \sum_{\alpha_{1}=0}^{\infty}...\sum_{\alpha_{k}=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}} = \prod_{a=1}^{k}(\frac{p_{a}}{p_{a}-1}) < \infty$$
but by claim 3 we have
$$\sum_{x \in \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} A_{j}} \frac{1}{x} \geq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9j} = \infty$$
a contradiction.

Hence by Claim 4 and Claim 2 there are primes that are arbitrarily large that divide $l$ but this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for solution! Where had Claim 1 come from? Is $\frac{j}{9}$ the minimum number of digits of $\ell^{n_j}$? If so, please consider that $A_j = P_{\ell^{n_j}}$ is a standard set (contains **distinct** numbers).

Comment: To prove Claim 1 note that $l^{n_{j}}$ consists of atleast $\frac{j}{9}$ positive digits (not $0$). Now choose some $\lceil\frac{j}{9}\rceil$ such digits of $l^{n_{j}}$, there are atleast $\frac{j}{9}$ distinct sums in the interval $[1,j]$ as each such digit is between $1$ and $9$.

Comment: $\frac{j}{9}$ would be the minimum number of $\textit{positive}$ digits of $l^{n_{j}}$